# Stripe Get Subscription ID after Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I am creating a subscription model for a test webapp using the Stripe gem. I am able to create the subscription and delete it entering the subscription ID manually but I want to save the subscription to my database so I don't have to do that. This is what I have so far:

```
 customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    card: token,
    email: current_user.email
    )

 Stripe::Subscription.create(
    customer: customer.id,
    plan: 000
    )

 current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
 current_user.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id
```

I get an error stating there is no Subscription ID. How do I get the subscription ID? I need it so I can cancel the subscription when requested. I tired looking through the API but it doesn't explicitly say how to retrieve the Subscription API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh... I forgot to assign the subscription. I changed the first line from:

`Stripe::Subscription.create()`

to:

`subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create()`

And now it works.